# Adding styles to innerHTML

Tags: html, css

I'm having errors when adding styles to this element

```
<div [innerHTML]="lesson.body | mdToHtml" class="item item__lesson"></div>
```

It has a markdown format, so when it renders looks like a post. So I want to add some styles to the paragraph. When i put

```
p {
 font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Nothing happens, I've tried with different classes. But no results. Any suggestions or ideas? thanks

Comment: Can you recreate a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the issue? Please include the rendered HTML that your markdown generates as well as relevant CSS.

Comment: As far as I know, p != div.

Comment: @VXp Good point. I'm assuming a `<p>` gets generated inside the `<div>`, but hard to tell as of yet.

Comment: @showdev True, could be, just shouting out the obvious.

Comment: Ok, i have the data on firebase, so I made the render, and I'm trying to add some styles to the data, so I put it as markdown and I want to add some styles. I think it's because it adds the styles to the file but when that happen the innerHTML is not append yet. But its weird because it should work.

Comment: Yes, the <p> its generated inside the div